# SAML Token: Why use multiple Hash/Digest Algorithms: sha256 and sha1?

Tags: digital-signature, saml-2.0

I'm reading this [IBM Developer Works SAML article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mw-1703-maurip1-bluemix/index.html), where you can see two different signature/digest algorithms below: sha1 and sha256. I'm curious why both are listed and what is being signed by which method. That article says, "the [IdP] applies a hashing algorithm to the content of the Assertion element." That seems to be sha256, but then why mention DigestMethod sha1? If both methods are hashing the same content, how would the service provider (SP) know to verify the signature using sha256 when sha1 is the DigestMethod?

Is this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358612/signaturemethod-algorithm-vs-digestmethod-algorithm-in-xml-signature) the correct explanation?

> ...the DigestMethod Algorithm elements refer to their parent Reference element. You can have different DigestMethod Algorithms for your multiple Reference elements, and again a different SignatureMethod Algorithm to hash and sign all the References.

```
<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
      ID="Assertion1487321564650" IssueInstant="2017-02-17T08:52:44.650Z"
      Version="2.0"> 
    <saml2:Issuer>samlsso.sample.net</saml2:Issuer> 
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"> 
      <ds:SignedInfo> 
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /> 
        <ds:SignatureMethod
          Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /> 
        <ds:Reference URI="#Assertion1487321564650"> 
          <ds:Transforms> 
            <ds:Transform
              Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /> 
            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /> 
           </ds:Transforms> 
          <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /> 
          <ds:DigestValue>nKYxEAMG1LY4H+LqR22KJ/vqyb8=</ds:DigestValue> 
        </ds:Reference> 
      </ds:SignedInfo> 
      <ds:SignatureValue> 
m5V44OFKU1PMdibileobvVVA8NVZMKRmKAauOin2f+Kr1WQ   [...]   Z/5JcU/qw== 
      </ds:SignatureValue> 
      <ds:KeyInfo> 
        <ds:X509Data> 
          <ds:X509Certificate> 
MIIDRzCCAi+gAwIBAgIEKa/crTANBgkq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML element `SignedInfo` is what is being signed using the private key and SHA-256. Not shown is the actual signature algorithm but if you look up rsa-sha256 then you'll find that it uses the PKCS#1 v1.5 signature scheme rather than the newer PSS.

This `SignedInfo` contains the reference to the signed data, the transformations (canonicalization) and the signature value of the signed data. This is not part of the data within the regular signature generation; that can only contain a hash value. So the meta-information is signed as well. There can be multiple references and different kind of transformations in `SignedInfo`.

Of course the references themselves must be signed together with the hash over the data; otherwise you could for instance switch the data around when two data blocks have been hashed.

You should however still verify that the hash is over the correct data within your application. Otherwise you will verify some data in the XML, while processing entirely different data. This should of course be performed by the SAML implementation.

More information can of course be retrieved from [the XML-digsig standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/).

---

Yes, the linked-to StackOverflow post is correct.

---

I'll not lament the fact that SHA-1 is used calculate the hash over the data. SHA-1 has been broken and should not be used anymore; and certainly not for data hashing or signature generation.